# Firebase Function (NodeJS) says "ref is not a function"

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I've created a Firebase Function that is supposed to fire when I add a new document, and then the function creates an image by pulling some data from the document. I could have sworn this was working yesterday, but now when I upload a document, the Function throws an error telling me that "ref" is not a function. I've followed the online Firebase docs and I think I have what I need here (ref is being required) so I'm confused as to why I'm getting the error. Here are the relevent bits...

```
const { getStorage, ref } = require("firebase-admin/storage"); // <- ref is required
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");

initializeApp();

const storage = getStorage();

exports.createFbAd = onDocumentCreated("/quizzes/{documentId}", async (event) => {
    // Create a new image and store it in Storage
    const canvasWidth = 1200; // Set the canvas width
    const canvasHeight = 630; // Set the canvas height
    const canvas = createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    logger.log("Created canvas");

    // Get the reference to the ad image in Firebase Storage
    const fbAdRef = ref(storage, 'fb ad base.jpg'); // ERROR 'ref is not a function'
    ...
    ...
});
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This typically happens when you have a `ref` variable defined somewhere between the `import` and the line where the error appears. It doesn't show in the code you shared, but check your real code as that is the common cause.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I just double checked (it's a small file) and did a search just to be sure, but "ref" is never mentioned anywhere else at the moment.

Comment: Oh right... what you get here is **not** a variant of the regular client-side SDK, but a variant of the Google Cloud SDK for Cloud Storage. I'm a bit surprise that the import doesn't give an error in that case though. Either way, if my assumption is correct, base your code on this SDK: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Node.js Admin SDK for Cloud Storage is **not** a variant of the client-side SDKs, but a variant of the GCP SDK. So you'll want to use [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest) and [this](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/) to base your code on.